# Curator: committing transaction

Tags: java, apache-curator

Instances of Apache Curator's CuratorFramework class allow mutation operations to be run `inTransaction()`. I'm currently using these calls, but can't figure out how to commit them.

Looking at the [CuratorTransaction JavaDoc](https://curator.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/curator/framework/api/transaction/CuratorTransaction.html), it clearly states:

> **Important:**
>        the operations are not submitted until [`CuratorTransactionFinal.commit()`](https://curator.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/curator/framework/api/transaction/CuratorTransactionFinal.html#commit--) is called.

However, `CuratorTransactionFinal` is an interface with no implementing classes (that I can find).

Am I expected to implement it and define the functionality of `commit()`?
Or am I missing some larger concept?

Comment: Note: those transaction APIs are deprecated in favor of never ones. Examples of the newer API are here: https://github.com/apache/curator/blob/master/curator-examples/src/main/java/framework/TransactionExamples.java

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found it in the source code:

Assuming your instance of CuratorFramework is called "client".

if you perform an operation like...

```
client.create().forPath("/foo");
```

...it is not transactional. If you perform...

```
client.inTransaction().create.forPath("/foo");
```

...it is, but the operation will not actually be completed until you commit the transaction. This much I already knew. To commit the transaction, you do:

```
client.inTransaction().create().forPath("/foo")
    .and().create().forPath("/bar")
    .and().commit();
```